# writing queue for websocket

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I use websocket for connecting a server on my code like:

```
var WS = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.domain + ":3232/sc");
```

There are 4 readyState, WebSockets' state parameter, and I want to implement a queue and it wait OPEN state before sending data on socket.

How can do it an efficient and regular way? What is the best practice of this situation?

For more information WebSocket state; [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket)

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with the "onopen" event?

```
WS.onopen = function(){

   // do stuff
};
```

Comment: Assume that when client connect to server, it send some dynamic messages. Therefore I cannot add them into onOpen event. Or asumme that there is a problem and connection is broken in websocket. Messages should not be be lost. When connection establish, messages have to be sent on websocket.